# ASP.NET MVC - How do I implement Paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor, pagination

I'm relatively new to MVC and looking to output some data and paginate through it. I don't want some fancy JQuery pagination or anything like that, it has to run server side. I have done this sort of thing previously using Gridviews etc, but not sure how to achieve this using ASP.NET MVC. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

I am using the following:

Razor,
C#
Entity Framework,
LINQ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a paging solution for ASP.NET MVC that does paging in the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105336/is-there-a-paging-solution-for-asp-net-mvc-that-does-paging-in-the-database)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paging & Sorting grids with ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496470/paging-sorting-grids-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

This is a famous tutorial http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that this should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx